# htaccess: Redirect sub-folder to another sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I require to do 301 redirects via the htaccess file however, I am having difficulty to redirect sub-folder which are two levels down. In case it is important, `index.php` resolves to `/`

Scenario:
`www.domain.com/oldfolder1/oldfolder2/` shall be redirect to `www.domain.com/newfolder/`

Also, the following rule exists as it is required

```
Redirect 301 /oldfolder1/ http://www.domain.com/newfolder/
```

The problem I am having is that currently the redirect ends up on www.domain.com/newfolder/oldfolder2/ which is wrong and shall not be. The page must end on www.domain.com/newfolder/

I have tried the following but nothing worked

Method 1:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder1/oldfolder2/(.*) /newfolder/$1
```

Method 2:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfolder1/oldfolder2 http://www.domain.com/newfolder/
```

Method 3:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfolder1/oldfolder2 http://www.domain.com/newfolder/index.php
```

Can you please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead and put this in your htaccess file. See how that works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldfolder1/oldfolder2/?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oldfolder1/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/newfolder/ [R=301,L]
```

Edit:

Based on your comment.

```
RewriteEngine On 
#if directory exists redirect to equivalent folder. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^oldfolder1/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/newfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
#if it's not a directory then redirect to main folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^oldfolder1/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/newfolder/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Panama Jack, I will try that but please note that this rule also exists. Would this have impact on it?    Redirect 301 /oldfolder1/ http://www.domain.com/newfolder/

Comment: Remove that redirect rule and just use the one rule. See my updated answer.

Comment: Any additional info you have, needs to always be added to your original question. So edit your question if you have more info to add. If the answer that is provided works for you then be sure to accept the answer which will increase your rep and allow you to do more stuff.

Comment: Hi, ok I will try that. With that also automatically turn e.g. /oldfolder1/oldfolder3/ into /newfolder/oldfolder3/ ?

Comment: No it will not. That would take tweaking of the rule. This only solves the problem you asked. But yes it can be made to that also.

Comment: how can one do that? what would be the rule for that?

Comment: Then you can use one rule like this to match any folder after oldfolder1 `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldfolder1/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/newfolder/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: does this clash with the other rules?

Comment: You would need to use it instead of the rule in my original answer if you want to match all folders. Not both rules.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that some folders within olderfolder1 dont exist anymore and need to be going only to newfolder

Comment: I edited the rule so if it doesn't exist it will go to newfolder. See my updated answer. If you have more questions about other rules, feel free to ask a new question and that will be answered too. :)